# onLoadingComplete Universal Imageloader not called

Tags: android, universal-image-loader

I have to do some stuff immediately after image has been loaded. I am using `SimpleImageLoadingListener` to listen for callback methods, but strangely `onLoadingComplete` never gets called, but `onLoadingStarted` does. I have checked that there is no call to image loading fail or cancel methods - that means there is no error. Can anyone point out the reason and steps to correct it. Thanks.

```
 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

         ImageView img = new ImageView(mContext);
         img.setLayoutParams(new Gallery.LayoutParams(coverflowWidth, coverflowHeight));
         img.setScaleType(ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
         img.setTag(position);

        ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageURL, img, options,  new SimpleImageLoadingListener()

        {
            boolean cacheFound;

            @Override
            public void onLoadingStarted(String url, View view) {
                List<String> memCache = MemoryCacheUtil.findCacheKeysForImageUri(url, ImageLoader.getInstance().getMemoryCache());
                cacheFound = !memCache.isEmpty();
                if (!cacheFound) {
                    File discCache = DiscCacheUtil.findInCache(url, ImageLoader.getInstance().getDiscCache());
                    if (discCache != null) {
                        cacheFound = discCache.exists();
                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {

          //never gets called
                ImageView image = (ImageView) view;

                if (cacheFound) {

                image.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);

               }

                else
                {
                    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageURL, image, options, null);
                }   

            }
        });

     return img;

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually making request to load same image 2 times from different places. So `onLoadingComplete` was called for another code snippet, not for the one I mentioned above. Silly me... it was a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 0):

In my case i was passing **filepath as a string** whereas it asks for filePath's URI as first parameter to `ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imageURL, img, options,  new SimpleImageLoadingListener())`;